# Simply namespaces in PHP

Tags: php, namespaces

I want to include class `Proxy` from
*./proxy/Proxy.php* in *./index.php*

```
require_once 'proxy/Proxy.php';
$proxy = new Proxy();
```

But next I want to use namespaces so I made:

*./proxy/Proxy.php*

```
namespace proxy;
class Proxy
{
[...]
```

and

*./index.php*

```
$proxy = new \proxy\Proxy();
```

or

```
$proxy = new proxy\Proxy();
```

or

```
use proxy\Proxy;
$proxy = new Proxy();
```

and I always get:
`Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'proxy\Proxy' not found in /var/www/proxy/index.php`

What is wrong?

Comment: You still need to include the class file.... using namespacing for a class doesn't automagically do the includes for you, it simply namespaces them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, if you are going to use namepaces, make them PSR-4 autoloader compliant! Check this link:

http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/

In other words, I'm asking you to change your namespace to `Proxy` with a capital.

Secondly, to get autoloading working, you need to register an autoloader. You can do it yourself by checking this out http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php, or, the better way is to install Composer (https://getcomposer.org/).

Using Composer then, if you aren't currently using it, run `composer init` from your site root, which will generate a `composer.json`.

Inside the Json, add this entry:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": { 
        "Proxy": "src/" 
    },
},
```

That assumes all classes beginning with namespace Proxy go in the `src` directory.

Since you made changes to the autoloading config, run `composer dumpautoload` and it will generate fresh classmaps.

Finally, in your scripts, `require_once 'vendor/autoload.php` and you'll never need `require` a class again!

```
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Proxy\Proxy;

$proxy = new Proxy();
```

The convention is based on file path and name, so `src/Proxy.php` is `namepace Proxy`, `class Proxy`. `src/Something/Else.php` would be `namespace Proxy\Something` with `class Else`.

Have fun! :-D

Answer (score 1):

Try the following inside your index.php:

```
include 'proxy/Proxy.php';
use proxy\Proxy;

$proxy = new Proxy();
```

This file with the class needs to be included in order to be accessible. Just calling its namespace isn't enough.

Answer (score 0):

^^The comment from mega6382I should do the trick.

But I wanted to maybe help you any further in your development, I'd suggest you want to autoload the files when you need them? You can use PHP it's own autoloader for it: "[spl_autoload_register](http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php)!".
I'd also recommend you use some better namespaces, \proxy\Proxy makes no sense at all...